# comparison between matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two symplectic matrices of dimension $2n_1\times 2n_1$ and $2n_2\times 2n_2$ respectively;
Let $P_1>0$ and $P_2>0$  be the positive definite solutions of the following equations

$$ \left[\begin{array}{cc}
I_{n_1} & -P_{1}\end{array}\right]M_{1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
P_{1}\\
I_{n_1}
\end{array}\right]
 =0$$
and

$$ \left[\begin{array}{cc}
I_{n_2} & -P_{2}\end{array}\right]M_{2}\left[\begin{array}{c}
P_{2}\\
I_{n_2}
\end{array}\right]
 =0$$
My question is: what is the condition between $M_1$ and $M_2$ which involves that $trace(P_1)<trace(P_2)$?